# Can we delete records in share table with row cause as Rule?

Tags: apex, opportunity, sharing

```
delete [Select o.UserOrGroupId, o.RowCause, o.OpportunityId, o.OpportunityAccessLevel, o.Id From OpportunityShare o where RowCause='Rule' and  o.OpportunityId='######'];
```

Trying the above and looks like we cant delete data in share table with rowcause as Rule .Any ideas can this be done as admin through apex ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not possible, according to the documentation:
"All implicit sharing added by Force.com managed sharing cannot be altered directly using the Salesforce user interface, SOAP API, or Apex"

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_understanding.htm

In order to get rid of this, you need to change the Sharing Rule causing the share.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should be able to delete a record with Sharing type Rule

```
If(Trigger.IsUpdate){
List<OpportunityShare > sharesToDelete = [Select o.UserOrGroupId, o.RowCause, o.OpportunityId, o.OpportunityAccessLevel, o.Id From OpportunityShare where RowCause=:Schema.RowCause.Your_Sharing_Rule__Here and  o.OpportunityId='######'];
}
```

Followed up by

```
if (!sharesToDelete.isEmpty()) {
        delete sharesToDelete;
    }
```

It is also demonstrated [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_recalc.htm)

Comment: Rowcause='Rule' implies that this is an implicit sharing governed by Sharing Rules. What you describe is deleting sharing records that have been created via Managed Sharing. That is perfectly possible, but in my view is not what the questions was about.